# JsonConverter byte[]

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, json.net

I have the following code:

//Models

```
public class Home{
    public Guid HomeId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Description1 { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual Perfil Perfil { get; set; }
}

public class Perfil
{
    public Guid UserId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public byte[] Description2 { get; set; }
}
```

// JsonConverter

```
public class ByteArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(byte[]);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        var m = Convert.FromBase64String((string)reader.Value);
        return m;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])value;
        writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
    }
}
```

// Serialize (Calls the WriteJson function of the ByteArrayConverter, OK)

```
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);

{
"HomeId": "2925362b",
"UserId": "9ea43c30",
"Name": "Name 1",
"Description1": "VABlAHMAdABlAA==", //===> Converts to Base64 (OK)
"User": {
    "UserId": "9ea43c30",
    "Email": "aaaa@aaaa.com",
    "Perfil": {
        "UserId": "9ea43c30",
        "Name": "Name 2",
        "Description2": "dABlAHMAdABlAA==", //===> Converts to Base64  (OK)
    }
}
```

}

// Deserialize

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized, settings); // T is class Home

 {
"HomeId": "2925362b",
"UserId": "9ea43c30",
"Name": "Name 1",
"Description1": "VABlAHMAdABlAA==", //===> Don't Convert from Base64,  (**Does not call the ReadJson function of ByteArrayConverter**)
"User": {
    "UserId": "9ea43c30",
    "Email": "aaaa@aaaa.com",
    "Perfil": {
        "UserId": "9ea43c30",
        "Name": "Name 2",
        "Description2": "dABlAHMAdABlAA==", //===> Convert from Base64 (OK)
    }
}
```

}

Settings

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
        settings.Converters.Add(new ByteArrayConverter());
```

The Description1 property does not get into the ReadJson function of the ByteArrayConverter class, so it does not convert back the byte [], generating another invalid [] byte, ....

Any idea of this problem?

Comment: Why are you using a converter at all?  Json.NET supports base64 for byte arrays natively, see the [Serialization Guide: Primitive Types](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm)

Comment: Hi, when I do not use as above, it serializes a byte[] type with the information: $ type: "System.Byte [], mscorlib"
$ Value: "VABlAHMAdABlAA ==", but when I go deserialize it shows an error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Comment: FWIW, it worked fine for me without the converter using the same settings you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but need clarification

> when I do not use as above, it serializes a byte[] type with the information: $ type: "System.Byte [], mscorlib" $ Value: "VABlAHMAdABlAA ==", but when I go deserialize it shows an error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

To avoid the above error in deserialization, use the following json setting in deserialization.

```
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None
```

TypeNameHandling setting include type information when serializing JSON and read type information so that the create types are created when deserializing JSON

For more details read: [TypeNameHandling Enumeration](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm)

The serialization of byte[] is Base-64 string, and when deserialized it generate byte[] again.

You need not ByteArrayConverter as given in the comments of @Brian Rogers and @dbc

You can find [a complete working example using your code with modification online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ljxRHS)